# Bootable "live" partition on 1TB External HDD

Tags: boot, grub2, partitioning, live-cd, disk-utility

I have a 1TB WD Passport. I made a 20GB partition, formatted to FAT, for a persistent live Ubuntu install. The rest I formatted as NTFS, to be used for backups.

I made the 20GB live install with Ubuntu Startup Disk Creator. The entire drive was previously formatted with Ubuntu Disk Utility; 20GB FAT, Remainder NTFS.

Ubuntu Startup Disk Creator ran with no errors. However, when I boot, and select the WD Passport as the first boot disk I get a black screen with a cursor in the corner.

Is there something special I have to do to boot from this partition?

Here is the partition table from the hard drive:

```
   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1   *          63    39070079    19535008+  83  Linux
/dev/sdb2        39070080  1953455804   957192862+   7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Please pastebin `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`.

Answer (score 0):

Especially since you have the space for it, I would highly recommend doing a normal installation of Ubuntu (following the same steps you would for an install to an internal disk, but selecting the external instead) rather than a persistant live install. Among other things, a "persistant" live installation cannot be properly upgraded.

That said, a persistant live install obviously shouldn't be giving you a blinking cursor at boot, but I do still think that doing a normal install will fix this because a normal installation will be using grub rather than syslinux as the bootloader.

If after doing a normal install to the USB drive you still get the same problem, or if you really for some reason do want to stick with a persistant Live install, please run boot info script http://bootinfoscript.sourceforge.net/ and post the RESULTS.txt which it produces.

Comment: Well after rebooting it said "unable to find file$boot". I typed "help" and it went to a text installer, even more rudimentary than the alternate installer. Never saw that before. It booted and I installed just fine. The only problem I have now is that the "free disk space" reported by the System Config GUI is 256GB while I only have a 128GB SSD. OFF TOPIC: Could this be because I used btrfs?